# Passing type parameter to self-referential pointer

Tags: c++, class, templates, definition

```
template <class T>
class Node {
    private:
        T m_value;
        //Node* m_ptr;    //(1)
        //Node<T>* m_ptr; //(2)
};
```

Can someone explain what is the difference between the above two statements (1) and (2)? Both statements seem to compile, but I can't seem to find what the ISO C++ says about them.

Comment: There is no difference between 1 and 2. When a class name is used inside it's definition like this it refers to the current instantiation.

Comment: It's called the injected class name. You don't need to apply template arguments when you are in the scope of a class template. This also applies for its bases classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are the same thing, because you declare the pointer inside the template, thus when you create an instance of `Node` the compiler knows what `T` is. You don't have to specify the type for a template if it can be deduced, e.g. from argument types, or in this case from the template instance the pointer belongs to.

```
template <class T>
class Node {
public:
    T m_value;
    Node* m_ptr;    //(1)
    //Node<T>* m_ptr; //(2)
};

int main()
{
    Node<float> test;
    test.m_ptr = new Node<float>{}; // valid
    test.m_ptr = new Node<bool>{};  // invalid - triggers compiler error
    auto val = test.m_ptr->m_value; // val will be of float type
}
```

Answer (score 9):

According to the C++ Standard (14.6.1 Locally declared names)

> 3 The injected-class-name of a class template or class template
>   specialization **can be used either as a template-name or a type-name**
>   wherever it is in scope. [ Example:

```
template <class T> struct Base {
Base* p;
};
template <class T> struct Derived: public Base<T> {
typename Derived::Base* p; // meaning Derived::Base<T>
};
template<class T, template<class> class U = T::template Base> struct Third { };
Third<Base<int> > t; // OK: default argument uses injected-class-name as a template
```

> — end example ]

Thus these data member declarations

```
Node* m_ptr;    //(1)
Node<T>* m_ptr; //(2)
```

are equivalent because the injected class name `Node` is used in the scope of the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

They are "the same"

I think that's what it is happening is, in the case of

> Node* m_ptr_n

The compiler makes the type match the class type.

In the case of

> Node < T>* m_ptr

What it's created is a pointer to a class witch template matches with the "T" type.

If you want to get an int instance that points to a float instance what you can do is pass both types to the template.

```
template <class T1, class T2, class T3>
    class Node {
    public:
         T1 m_value;
         // Node* m_ptr_n;    //(1)
         Node<T2, T3>* m_ptr; //(2)
    };
```